# Code First - Validating Password and also Hashing with same entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, password-protection

1. Code First
2. Entity Framework
3. C# Visual Studio 2012

I have a user account entity that validates a password against a regular expression

is there an event I can use that will convert the password to a hashed value just before saving to the database?

My problem is that if I hash the password first then I cant validate using this entity.

I have thought about extracting the validation to a different area and only saving the the hashed value to the entity.

The current flow is as follows

1. User enters new account details
2. User Account entity created
3. Entity validated using dataannotations
4. Password hashed
5. Entity saved to database

Can someone help me please with thoughts on where to place the password hashing

Answer (score -1):

If you are using MVC, my approach would be something like -

Put the regex on the Password field of the Account class.

Thhe in the AccountController Create method :

1. check if the model state is valid - this will verify the regex and
   all other required fields.
2. call your hashing method and replace the existing plain text password with hashed password on the account object
3. save to the database

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public ActionResult Create(User user)
   {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           user.Password = PasswordHasher.Hash(user.Password);
           db.Users.Add(user);
           db.SaveChanges();
           return RedirectToAction("Index");
       }

       return View(user);
   }
   ```